# Sequential execution of async operations in Android

Tags: java, android

Sequential execution of asynchronous operations in Android is at least complicated.
Sequential execution that used to be a semi-colon between two operators like in `do_this(); do_that()` now requires chaining listeners, which is ugly and barely readable.

Oddly enough, the examples that demonstrate the need for chaining sequential operations usually look contrived, but today I found a perfectly reasonable one.

In Android there is in-app billing, an application can support multiple so-called in-app products (also known as SKU = stock keeping unit), letting the user, for example, buy (pay for) only the functionality that he/she needs (and, alas, also letting bearded men sell bitmaps to teenagers).

The function that retrieves in-app product info is

```
public void queryInventoryAsync(final boolean querySkuDetails,
                                final List<String> moreSkus,
                                final QueryInventoryFinishedListener listener)
```

and it has a restriction that the list must contain at most 20 items. *(Yes it does.)*
Even if only a few of these 20 are registered as in-app products.

I want to retrieve, say, information about one hundred in-app products. The first thought would be to invoke this function in a loop, but only one asynchronous operation with the market is allowed at any moment.

One may of course say "do not reuse, change the source", and even provide very good arguments for that, and this is probably what I will finally do, but I write this because I want see an elegant reuse solution.

***Is there an elegant (=not cumbersome) pattern or trick that allows to chain several asynchronous operations in the general case?***

(I underline that the asynchronous operation that uses a listener is pre-existing code.)

UPD this is what is called "callback hell" ( http://callbackhell.com/ ) in the JavaScript world.

Comment: I have to admit, I have never developed on Android, but doesn't this defeat the whole reason one would use async tasks?  If you needed to run them serially, why not leave them as synchronous tasks and run them one after another?  Or are you trying to make some library designed to work asynchronously work as if synchronous?

Comment: Why dont you use a Message Handler and pass messages to it ?

Comment: @CodeChimp There already is a function that does what I want, I just want to call it N times. What you propose is _redesign_, while I want to _reuse_ if that is possible. [In fact, I understand that your proposal is: _do not use that async-wrapped version, instead use the sync version in a loop and put that into an async wrapper._ Very reasonable. OTOH, sometimes the sync version is just not there, e.g. in the case on inter-process communication.]

Comment: I can understand if it's pre-existing code, and you are just trying to make your stuff work within it's limitations.  That's why I asked...just in case you were designing this from the ground up as Async when it sounds like you want Sync.  I was just trying to make sure you are not trying to solve an architecture issue by over-engineering.

Answer (score 0):

You can sequence `AsyncTask`s one after the other by calling the `execute()` method of the next `AsyncTask` in the `onPostExecute()` method of the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

[Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)s are useful for sequential work on any thread, not only on the UI thread.

Check out [HandlerThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html), create a Handler based on its Looper, and post background work to the handler.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [ReactiveX promises exactly this](http://reactivex.io/intro.html).

http://blog.danlew.net/2014/09/22/grokking-rxjava-part-2/

```
query("Hello, world!") // Returns a List of website URLs based on a text search
    .flatMap(urls -> Observable.from(urls))
    .flatMap(url -> getTitle(url)) // long operation
    .filter(title -> title != null)
    .subscribe(title -> System.out.println(title));
```

ReactiveX for Android:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid

Retrolambda: https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda (Lambdas for Java 5,6,7)